# Where Can I Learn How to Program for Windows Phone 7.5?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, expression-blend

I have just finished [Bob Tabor's Windows Phone 7 Development for Absolute Beginners series](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-7-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Series-Introduction). I have learned a lot, but I don't know where to go from here. I have an app in mind (a Chemistry Helper) and would like to learn about:

- Silverlight
- C#
- Windows Phone Developing (mostly this)
- XAML
- and Expression Blend for the Windows Phone.

I wish to learn about these so I can implement them in my program for the Windows Phone. The question is, where can I find some help for this? Are there any series on YouTube that could help? Does Channel 9 have anything good? Please let me know any websites that can help me learn about developing for the Windows Phone 7.5! Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: I am really looking for a video tutorial. I work better when there is a video going and I can program with the instructor. If you have found a HTML or web tutorial, feel free to post it, but I don't think it will help as much as a video.**

**SECOND EDIT: I am also on a very tight budget. I would like something that is free or barely costs anything.**

Comment: Not sure why this was closed as not constructive. Anyway, you probably want this series in Channel9: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Get-to-Mango/Get-to-Windows-Phone-Mango-1-From-XNA-to-SLXNA. It has around 9 training videos for the new features in Windows Phone 7.5

Comment: @krolth: We discourage shopping-type questions here.  There's plenty of related discussion on [meta], if you care to search around.

Comment: This is good! Yeah, I looked at the FAQ, apparently this question meets the criteria...
Anyways, this looks really good, it's from Channel 9, it's free, legit, and it's a video! I'm going to use this! If this was an answer, I would mark it as an accepted answer! Thanks!

Comment: For other people, I have found a free e-book. Here's the link:
http://www.charlespetzold.com/phone/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the link to the Mango Training Kit:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh220612

Also there is this page that has labs and videos: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wp7mangotrainingcourse_mangonewfeatures_unit

EDIT:
Also, I know you wanted free but [pluralsight](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/) has some really good training videos for windows phone (including 7.5) and Silverlight.  They have a 10day free trial (up to 200minutes of video) and the plan starts at $29 per month. No contracts.

Comment: So far, I think your answer is the best. The only things are
A. The videos are mostly events held by Microsoft saying how they're phone is a good thing for developers to think about developing for (i.e. advertisement) and
B. These examples basically expect you to know a lot about C#. Don't get me wrong, I watched all of Bob's things and have a good basic knowledge of C#, bu I would like to continue learning C# as I develop for the platform.
But again, right now, your answer would probably be the best.

Actually I just remembered. I already looked at this HTML. It's not that helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check out www.create.msdn.com. I haven't done much with WP7 yet myself. If your looking for screencasts, your guess is as good as mine...

Comment: I have already tried their tutorials. They aren't very helpful. I am really looking for a video tutorial series. Let me edit my question

Answer (score 0):

I have used this book and it is very well written,[Windows Phone 7 Silverlight Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849691169)

Comment: Oh yes, and I'm on a very tight budget. But that looks like a good book if I did have some money!